# File System as a Service for Video Streaming

Tags: video, filesystems, cloud

I'm building a video streaming website.

Can someone please suggest a suitable File System which to store Video.

My server should be able to perform video manipulation on the stored video.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amazon [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for storage and [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) for streaming content delivery work well. There are also a lot of commercial services that can transcode your video before storing on S3. One example is [Zencoder](http://zencoder.com/en/).